# Plotar la combinación de vectores de una lista

Tags: r, datatables, lista, ggplot2, array

Tengo una *list* llamada *"dwc_ST"*, con dos niveles: en el primer nivel son 8 elementos (ST1 ... ST8). Cada uno de estos 8 elementos contiene 12 vectores en el segundo nivel. Es decir, tengo 12x8 = 96 vectores, divididos de 12 en 12 en 8 listas. He colocado los 12 vectores del primer nivel (ST1) y del último nivel (ST8) aquí, como un ejemplo.

> > List of 8
>
> $ ST1:List of 12
>
> ..$ D1 : num [1:2048] 0.0308 -0.1126 -0.0357 0.116 0.0467 ...
>
> ..$ D2 : num [1:2048] 0.0701 0.0271 -0.0494 -0.0223 0.0314 ...
>
> ..$ D3 : num [1:2048] 0.00939 0.00396 -0.00143 -0.00198 -0.00237 ...
>
> ..$ D4 : num [1:2048] -0.01729 -0.00456 0.0078 0.0135 0.01635 ...
>
> ..$ D5 : num [1:2048] -0.00685 0.01192 0.02945 0.03905 0.04488 ...
>
> ..$ D6 : num [1:2048] -0.31 -0.326 -0.338 -0.335 -0.325 ...
>
> ..$ D7 : num [1:2048] -0.444 -0.465 -0.484 -0.493 -0.496 ...
>
> ..$ D8 : num [1:2048] -0.0883 -0.0967 -0.1046 -0.1109 -0.1164 ...
>
> ..$ D9 : num [1:2048] 1.34 1.35 1.36 1.36 1.36 ...
>
> ..$ D10: num [1:2048] 0.68 0.682 0.683 0.684 0.685 ...
>
> ..$ D11: num [1:2048] 1.12 1.12 1.12 1.12 1.12 ...
>
> ..$ S11: num [1:2048] 56.3 56.3 56.3 56.3 56.3 ...
>
> . . .
>
> $ ST8:List of 12
>
> ..$ D1 : num [1:2048] 0.00391 -0.00153 -0.0307 0.04341 0.06447 ...
>
> ..$ D2 : num [1:2048] 0.023173 0.108501 0.195189 -0.000658 -0.256492
>   ...
>
> ..$ D3 : num [1:2048] 0.15 0.284 0.399 0.268 0.052 ...
>
> ..$ D4 : num [1:2048] -2.16 -2.78 -3.26 -2.87 -2.08 ...
>
> ..$ D5 : num [1:2048] 3.77 4.22 4.57 4.41 4.01 ...
>
> ..$ D6 : num [1:2048] -1.29 -1.34 -1.36 -1.33 -1.27 ...
>
> ..$ D7 : num [1:2048] -0.291 -0.313 -0.333 -0.344 -0.352 ...
>
> ..$ D8 : num [1:2048] 0.252 0.254 0.256 0.256 0.255 ...
>
> ..$ D9 : num [1:2048] 0.693 0.698 0.704 0.707 0.709 ...
>
> ..$ D10: num [1:2048] 0.276 0.276 0.276 0.276 0.275 ...
>
> ..$ D11: num [1:2048] 0.767 0.767 0.766 0.766 0.765 ...
>
> ..$ S11: num [1:2048] 75.4 75.4 75.4 75.4 75.4 ...

**Lo que necesito es poner en gráficos las combinaciones de estos vectores en 20 archivos, (8*13) + 12 = 124 gráficos de línea**, siendo:

1. 8 archivos (ST1 al ST8) para representar 11 vectores (D1, D2, D3 ... D11), cada ST[i] un archivo .jpg., *ejemplo de ilustración 1 abajo.*
2. 12 gráficos (D1, D2, D3, ..., D11, S11) para representar los vectores para cada ST, *ejemplo de ilustración 2 abajo.*

Para el primer caso, si bien los gráficos se podrían plotar uno a uno (el primer gráfico, línea 3, es de un vector de flujo, de una data.frame aparte), con:

```
plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(5,3))
plot(Flujo$ST1, type="l", ylab="Q (m³/s)", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$S11, type="l", ylab="A11", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
mtext("DWC ST1", side = 3, cex = 1.5, line = 1)
plot(dwc_ST1$D11, type="l", ylab="D11", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D10, type="l", ylab="D10", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D9, type="l", ylab="D9", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D8, type="l", ylab="D8", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D7, type="l", ylab="D7", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D6, type="l", ylab="D6", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D5, type="l", ylab="D5", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D4, type="l", ylab="D4", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D3, type="l", ylab="D3", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D2, type="l", ylab="D2", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
plot(dwc_ST1$D1, type="l", ylab="D1", xlab="Tiempo (h)")
```

Y el resultado de ST1 sería algo como:
[image: dwc_ST1.jpg]

Y así, sucesivamente hasta ST8.

Para el segundo caso, con el conjunto de los 12 gráficos (A11, D11, D10, D9 ... D1), podría aplicar este código, añadiendo las líneas una a una:

```
plot(dwc_ST1$D11, type="l", ylab="D11", col = "blue", lwd = 2, xlab="Tempo (h)", ylim = c(-4,3))
lines(dwc_ST2$D11, type="l", col = "lightblue", lwd = 2)
lines(dwc_ST3$D11, type="l", col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(dwc_ST4$D11, type="l", col = "green", lwd=2)
lines(dwc_ST5$D11, type="l", col = "darkred", lwd=2)
lines(dwc_ST6$D11, type="l", col = "darkgreen", lwd = 2)
lines(dwc_ST7$D11, type="l", col = "black", lwd=2)
lines(dwc_ST8$D11, type="l", col = "gray", lwd=2)
```

Y el resultado sería algo como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría simplificar este código; con un  "loop", por ejemplo. Pido su ayuda para conseguir. Yo ya intente de esta forma:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,3))
  for (i in seq_along(dwc_ST))  {
  plot.ts(dwc_ST[[i]], type = "l", lty = 2, xlab = 'horas', ylab = "Vazao", main=Main[i])
  }
```

Pero el mensaje de error es:

> Error in xy.coords(x, NULL, log = log) : 
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Con el comando:

```
list2env(dwc_ST, envir = globalenv())
```

Yo puedo separar la lista de dos niveles a sólo 1 nivel, pero formando 8 listas más pequeñas, cada una con 12 niveles, y tal vez esto simplifique el loop. Pero no consigo hacerlo.

**En fin, alguien me podría ayudar haciendo esas combinaciones de gráficos?**

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que no tengo la data de dwc_ST, entonces tendré que inventar uno.

**Simulo la data**

```
STN<-sample(iris[,1],2048,replace=T)
for (i in 1:11)  STN<-cbind(STN,sample(iris[,1],2048,replace=T))
colnames(STN)<-c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","D11","S11")
dwc_ST<-list(ST1=STN[sample(1:2048),],ST2=STN[sample(1:2048),],ST3=STN[sample(1:2048),],
         ST4=STN[sample(1:2048),],ST5=STN[sample(1:2048),],ST6=STN[sample(1:2048),],
         ST7=STN[sample(1:2048),],ST8=STN[sample(1:2048),])
```

**Ploteo las 12 variables de ST1 en un intervalo de 2048 horas**

```
plot.new()
  par(mfrow=c(3,4))
  for (i in 1:12) plot(1:2048,dwc_ST$ST1[,i],type = "l",xlab = "Tiempo (h)")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder guardar cada ploteo de ST1,ST2,ST3 ... ST12 en archivos PNG:

```
for (j in 1:8) {
png(paste(j,".png",sep = ""))
  plot.new()
  par(mfrow=c(3,4))
  for (i in 1:12) plot(1:2048,dwc_ST[[j]][,i],type = "l",xlab = "Tiempo (h)")
dev.off()
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Para el segundo caso**

```
plot.new()
  plot(1:2048,dwc_ST[[1]][,11],type = "l",xlab = "Tiempo (h)",col=rainbow(8)[1])
  for (i in 2:8) lines(1:2048,dwc_ST[[i]][,11],type = "l",xlab = "Tiempo (h)",col=rainbow(8)[i])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias derive! Yo intentaré ejecutar de noche.
Uma dúvida: o que significa "[,10]", en "dwc_ST[[1]][,10]" en el último código?

Comment: "[,10]" se refiere a la columna "D10". Ahora mismo acabo de corregir a "[,11]" ya que en tu segundo caso se trabaja con la columna "D11".

Comment: Estoy aplicando todavía, Derive.
Yo he conseguido el primer paso, con cambios para adaptar el nombre de las variables de cada gráfico.
Pero todavía estoy tratando de hacer un bucle para que el gráfico sea construido para cada ST [k].

Comment: En el segundo caso, uno de los problemas que me encontré es el range de valores. Cada coeficiente tiene valores diferentes, y no estoy sabiendo seleccionar el valor mínimo y máximo de los diversos vectores para definir ymin y ymax. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Seria preferible que publiques este problema como una pregunta aparte.